# Формирование JSON с HTML-тегами в содержимом

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

С фасада отправляется JSON на сервер. Одно из полей содержит в себе форматированный HTML-тегами текст:

```
var description = $('textarea#viewappPacketDescriptionAddForm').val().trim();
var data = '{"name":"' + packetName + '","parentId":"' + catId + 
        '","description":"' + $('<div/>').text(description).html() + '"}';
```

При парсинге получаю ошибку:

> Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value

Пришедший JSON имеет вид:

```
{"name":"Приложение","parentId":"3","description":"&lt;h1&gt;Hellow word&lt;/h1&gt;
             &lt;p&gt;text should be here&lt;/p&gt;"}
```

Как подготовить текст на клиенте для нормального парсинга с помощью `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй `JSON.stringify` вместо ручного формирования строки.